# Почему оставление комментария может быть после времени "последнего посещения"?

Tags: дефект, поддержка, статус-так-задумано

Если участник оставил комментарий позже, чем у него в профиле отображается время "последнего" посещения, может это считаться багом?

Comment: Ок, я уже увидел [ответ на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70232/timestamp-on-question-is-later-than-profiles-seen-must-be-some-time-traveller).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Краткий перевод [ответа с большой меты](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70235/340911):

> "Последнее посещение" - это не последнее посещение, а дата последней
>   проверки активности, вполне возможно что кто-то может иметь активность
>   между проверками.

Народ недоволен такой формулировкой, но тут уж ничего не сделаешь.

Comment: Наверное, тогда уж внутри интервала между проверками.

Comment: @alexolut, да, благодарю, не заметил. Думаю одно, пишу другое, а выходит внахлёст :)